# When is an anonymous function executed? It doesn't have a name to call!

Tags: lambda, anonymous-function

I know it's not executed immediatly, but then when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous function can also be executed as soon as defined, without binding it to any name at runtime. Javascript example:

```
var o = "hello world";
(function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
})(o);
```

This is commonly used to [create scopes](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scoping-anonymous-functions/).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it needn't have a name at *declaration* time, but it can be bound to a name at *runtime*.

For example in Python:

```
def do_it(some_func):
    # call some_func
    result = some_func()
    # do something else

do_it(lambda: 42)
```

So the lambda just returns "42" and doesn't have a name.  But when it's passed to the function `do_it`, it gets bound to the `some_func` parameter name.  So there *is* a name to call, which is then called.